# How to plot and estimate empirical CDF and cdf in matlab

Tags: matlab, ecdf

the question has already been raised several times, but mine differs a little from those previously voiced. There is a table (x value and  relative frequencies).

| x | 150 | 250 | 350 | 450 | 550 | 650 | 750 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| y | 1 | 2 | 8 | 30 | 18 | 16 | 5 |

I don’t really understand the meaning of the function `[f,x] = ecdf(y)` built into matlab, since I estimate and plot an empirical distribution function,

[image]

however, it is clearly not correct, if you build a histogram based on the selected data (x and y), then the resulting ECDF does not describe the correctly chosen distribution.

[image]

Therefore, such a question arose: *how to construct correctly ECDF function from the table* (empirical distribution function for **x** and having an array of relative frequencies)for the distribution function and from it directly estimate and plot cumulative distribution function?

My code for plot hist and ECDF:

```matlab
%% data
y = [1; 2; 8; 30; 18; 16; 5];
x = [150; 250; 350; 450; 550; 650; 750];
%% hist and polygon
figure(1)
bar(x,y,'LineWidth',1,...
    'FaceColor',[0.0745098039215686 0.623529411764706 1],...
    'EdgeColor',[0.149019607843137 0.149019607843137 0.149019607843137],...
    'BarWidth',1,...
    'BarLayout','stacked');
hold on
plot(x,y,'-o','Color','red','LineWidth',1)
hold off

%% ecdf
[ff,x] = ecdf(y);
x_e = [0;x];
figure(2)
stairs(x_e,ff,'Marker','o','LineWidth',1,'Color',[0.0745098039215686 0.623529411764706 1]);
set(gca,'GridAlpha',0.25,'GridLineStyle','--','MinorGridLineStyle','--',...
    'XGrid','on','XMinorGrid','on','YGrid','on');
xlim([0 780]);
```

Comment: The is very good documentation on this subject: https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/ecdf.html . You always get just a guess of the real population. The confidence bounds in the examples explain it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the `ecdf` function, because it takes the *data values* as input. Your inputs, on the other hand, seem to be the *population values* and their *absolute frequencies*. So you only need to

- normalize the frequencies to make them relative, and then
- compute their cumulative sum.

When plotting, I suggest you include some initial and final population values with respective normalized frequencies `0` and `1` for a clearer graph.

```
x = [150; 250; 350; 450; 550; 650; 750];
y = [1; 2; 8; 30; 18; 16; 5]; % example data
cdf = cumsum(y./sum(y)); % normalize, then compute cumulative sum
stairs([100; x; 900], [0; cdf; 1], 'linewidth', .8), grid on % note two extra values
```

[image]